# Android: Set strings.xml value from .java file

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Ok this is going to be worded weird but I was wondering if there was a way to set one of the string values in `values/strings.xml` to a `static final` variable from one of the `.java` files. For example say I have the following basic class:

```
public class ConstantValue {
     public static final String VALUE = "custom val";
}
```

and I would get this value in the `strings.xml` file like so:

*idea code*

```
 <string name="custom_val">com.package.ConstantValue.VALUE</string>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because I believe that `strings.xml` is compiled into a class of its own _before_ the build gets to your actual activity source code.  This is why the string bundle is available for use in your Java code.  I could not find documentation on this, hence this remains as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because `string.xml` resources are added to `R.java`,
and `R.java` is an auto generated file contains all your resources used in the project. and if you want to change R.java you can't.

This is a basic thing in Android. You have to read Android Developers documents, then you will get good knowledge about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, because strings.xml is precompiled file. Use SharedPreferences to save runtime-depending strings.